# Window Unresponsive after using root.after() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I call method using `root.after(1000,timer_update)` my program freezes.
When I opened debugging mode, I found that after the command, the program stops at `root.mainloop()` and the method does not get called.

Code:

```
def timer_update():
    # Lots of code
    play_btn['image']=play_img
    root.update()
    playsound('sounds/Complete-1.mp3')
    # To show notification in Win 10
    if i==0 or i%2==0:
        toaster.show_toast(title="Break Time",msg="Break Time has started. Take some rest.",icon_path='images/icon.ico',duration=5)
    elif i%2!=0:
        toaster.show_toast(title="Break Over",msg="Break Time is Over. Let's get back to work.",icon_path='images/icon.ico',duration=5)
    i+=1
    try:
        time = seq[i]*60
    except IndexError:
        i = 0
        time = seq[i]*60
    play_btn['image']=pause_img
    root.update()
    run = root.after(1000,timer_update)
```

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe with lots of code there is `time.sleep()`

Comment: @CoolCloud There is no `time.sleep()`

Comment: Or maybe something that holds the `mainloop()`. Post an example of your code

Comment: @CoolCloud I have a condition in the function. When I call it in the `if` code block it works fine, when I call in the `else` block. It freezes

Comment: Whats in the `else`

Comment: @CoolCloud The code that is just updated.

Comment: Don't `root.update()` when not necessary!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Why? Can it cause a problem ?

Comment: Try saying `show_toast(.....,threaded=True)` for the `else`

Comment: @CoolCloud I'm not sure what you mean by that ?

Comment: Add an option to your toast, `threaded=True` like `toaster.show_toast(title="Break Over",msg="Break Time is Over. Let's get back to work.",icon_path='images/icon.ico',duration=5,threaded=True)`

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks Man. That Worked! Can you explain why and how `threaded=True` was causing trouble?

Comment: Where is the `toaster` object coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that your toast takes 5 seconds to be shown, so in that 5 seconds your GUI will be frozen as it happens in the same thread as tkinter. So you need the toast to happen in the new thread, to do that `win10toast` has an option(`threaded=True`):

```
toaster.show_toast(title="Break Over",msg="Break Time is Over. Let's get back to work.",icon_path='images/icon.ico',duration=5,threaded=True)
```

Make sure to do the same in the `if` statement too.

**Explanation:**
Threading is nothing much, just like a normal thread, imagine cars going through a thread and they got into accident, so the thread might break, just like that, your tkinter runs on one thread and your `win10toast` runs with it causing the thread to freeze for 5 seconds, but with `threading` you make a new thread for that `win10toast` and hence the thread with tkinter is going smooth, while the thread with toast is active for 5 seconds, and it doesnt matter for the other thread.
To know more about threading, take basic reading [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: Thanks Man! The Explanation is Awesome !